# using scrapy parsing a website under same div

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to parse a website using scrapy.The html page pattern is as follows



```
div class="nameinfo"
     div class="namesub"
           span class="namesub">/span>
           span class="info">data of type 1 /span>
     /div
     div class="namesub">
          span class="namesub">/span>
          span class="info">data of type 2 /span>
    /div>

     div class="namesub">
          span class="namesub">/span>
          span class="info">data of type 3 /span>> 
    /div>
/div
```


I have three different types of data as labelled above. Any idea how can I get the required data. All of them are in span elements inside div with class attrib 'namesub'. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you should put inside your spider:

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

namesubs = hxs.select("//div[@class='namesub']")
for namesub in namesubs:
    item = MyItem()
    item["info"] = namesub.select('.//span[@class="info"]/text()').extract()[0]

    yield item
```

This code assumes you have defined `MyItem` item class with `info` field.

Hope that helps.